# wso2 bankingSampleNo artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application : BankingSample_1.0.0.car

Tags: wso2

I am studying with the [Retail Banking Sample](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS360/Retail+Banking+Sample)
  When I deploy the Composite Application Project into WSO2 App Server ,I see the following:

```
[2014-04-25 17:57:21,649]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  Deploying Carbon Application : BankingSample_1.0.0.car...
[2014-04-25 17:57:21,677]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.internal.ApplicationManager} -  No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application : BankingSample_1.0.0.car
```

How can I deploy `BankingSample_1.0.0.car` successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Server Role field value of the modules in the Composite Application Editor before you create the CAR file and deploy.

You should have "ApplicationServer" as the ServerRole for the respective modules which needs to be deployed to the App Server.

Hope this helps!

/Harshana

Comment: i'm sorry, i cant find the server role field, i think the problem is when i deploy the project i forgotten some operations. Thank you for you help